# Cordova simple example not working for emulate Android

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator

I'm trying to follow the [simple example](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.9.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html) from cordova's tutorial.

I was able to run and emulate everything in the browser using `cordova emulate browser` - I see the logo with "device is ready".

I created an AVD with 768MB RAM in eclipse but when I issue `cordova emulate android` it opens up the emulator with a blank screen.

The log

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 2 seconds
Built the following apk(s):
    c:\wamp\www\testapp\platforms\android\ant-build\CordovaApp-debug.apk
WARNING : no emulator specified, defaulting to Nexus5
Waiting for emulator...
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: Well I have this problem with the Hello World app. Coincidentally, I'm using a Nexus5 emulator, too!